# New JQuery 3 Not Working Correctly w/ Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making this post as I've been having this issue, and I'd like to make light of it. Perhaps others are having it, or can say whether my situation is a unique case. I recently downloaded the new version of jQuery (3.0.0) and linked it to a current project I'm working on. My Bootstrap dropdown / collapsing navbar would NOT work until I switch to an older version of Jquery (1.12.4.)

Has anyone else noticed something like this or had a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 is not compatible with jQuery 3. You can use the latest v2 jquery though.